# Trying to retrieve List of projects of particular user from public repository in GitHub

Tags: public, rest

I.m try to access git api url from angular application,  but its failing.

Http failure response for https://api.github.com/search/repos/:username/projects: 404 Not Found.

this url is working https://api.github.com/search/repositories/q='mm', it is returning list of user repositories matching with keyword mm.

I need to display under particular user repository matching projects.

ex: poetapp is the owner of public repository, under his repository, need to retrieve list of projects matching keyword.

if search keyword, java means need to return list of projects having java keyword.

can you please help me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could call call e.g.

```
https://api.github.com/users/BernhardLenz/repos/
```

and do a filter on the client side.

A query parameter could be appended to above url using ?q=name:cas. However I am not sure if above api endpoint supports filters.